# Firebase Notofication Request Various To

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is a way to send in a firebase notidication request, various to

```
header:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=

Body:
{ "data":
{
"title": "Firebase notification",
"detail": "I am firebase notification. you can customise me. enjoy"
},
"to" : "c_ejgKg_0rY:APA91bEtp77PP99UuDvza1gKOKAmfqVg3ZHflWYQUGPQJFCvWy3Ortswv45MjtT8LQaRoebLqSXPTeaO21hm7QVnG694GgVmALbK5LIDAsyohKlTFlQSlwcdYQmPS5GnLGjLwfA3b34z",
"sound":"default"
}
```

here an example of the request, please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `registration_ids` instead...

[image: FCM Documentation]

[Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP protocol | Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

```
header:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key =

Body:
{
    "data":
    {
        "title": "Firebase notification",
        "detail": "I am firebase notification. you can customise me. enjoy"
    },
    "registration_ids" : [ 
        "c_ejgKg_0rY:APA91bEtp77PP99UuDvza1gKOKAmfqVg3ZHflWYQUGPQJFCvWy3Ortswv45MjtT8LQaRoebLqSXPTeaO21hm7QVnG694GgVmALbK5LIDAsyohKlTFlQSlwcdYQmPS5GnLGjLwfA3b34z"
    ],
    "sound":"default"
}
```